# cakephp auth login problem, only white screen after login

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I’ve created a small cakePHP application that uses the auth component to manage an admin section for changes.

The problem I’m having ‘only in the production environment’ is that after I login all I can see is a blank white screen. I should be redirected to a ‘dashboard’ view. This blank screen is also what I get with all other ‘admin’ prefixed views that require a logged in user, thus the auth component.

What is strange about this are two things, (1) this works fine in the local host and (2) this application is a copy of one that works fine in both the local host and production.

What I’ve done to try and resolve this is:

-Checked the previous application copy; nothing different found

-Checked that the passwords were hashed

-Checked that the .htaccess file was uploaded in ASCII format (suggested by the host)

Any help with this is appreciated.

Ideally I’d like to understand how to trouble shoot this type of problem.

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Try to remove the content of tmp/cache/models and tmp/cache/persistent. Also, do you have debug mode set to 1?

Comment: I've tried all of the above (empty cache and set debug to 1) and what I get now is: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/27/8069127/html/app/app_controller.php:17) [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 742]

Comment: Before this message there should some thing printed on the page. May be any error or warning. Can you post that error or warning.

Comment: When debug was set to 1 there was no error message, only the warning I posted above. I looked at the error log and focused on the mention of the app controller file. Since I put the auth settings in each controller I didn't really need this file so I removed it. Once it was removed the pages rendered properly. All that was in the app controller file was a list of the Session and Request Handler components. Perhaps a combination of all changes (cache and removal of app controller) resolved this. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear out your tmp cache files anytime you move a cakephp project to a new server or folder. They are located in /app/tmp/cache/